# Split a list into equal parts?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, partitioning

I have an array of `size` elements, and I have a function that will split it into roughly equal sections. It does this by setting the size of the first `size-1` sections with `size/num_of_sections`, and setting the size of the last section with whatever is left. The code is simple, works correctly and looks like so:

```
int section_size = size / num_of_sections;
int last_section_size = size - ( section_size * (num_of_sections - 1) );
```

The only problem is that there are some combinations of `size` and `num_of_sections` that does not split very well. For example, if `size = 10` and `num_of_sections = 6`, then the first four sections will be 1 element each, and the last section will be 6 elements.

How can I change this to an algorithm that will split it up more evenly, specifically, so that all sections are either size `X` or `X+1`? In the above example, the first four sections would be size 2, then the last two sections will be 1 each. There would obviously need to be a third variable produced that indicates a section number where all previous sections up to and including it are size `X` and all following are size `X+1`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Comment: maybe try `section[0] = size/n; section[1] = (size - section[0])/(n-1); section[2] = (size-section[0]-section[1])/(n-2);` ...

Comment: (Both comments will produce the same result, but unless you need it to be very fast - which was the idea for the line drawing algorithm -, @pmg's is the simpler one to comprehend)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual approach, when you’re fine with grouping all the larger pieces, is

```
const int total=/*…*/,pieces=/*…*/;
const int base=total/pieces,extra=total%pieces;
```

Then the first `extra` (perhaps 0) pieces have size `base+1` and the (`pieces-extra`) others have size `base`.